# How to resize the rangeinput handle after creation?

Tags: javascript, html, input, range, jquery-tools

I am using this http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/rangeinput/scrollbar.html ( as a horizontal scrollbar )

When resizing using:

```
$('.handle').css('width', 550+"px");
```

or

```
$(".handle").width(550).click();
```

after changing the handle width from 800px to 550px ( while using a 1000px width slider ) the handle cant be draged until the end of the slider. It stucks on position 200px ( 1000px - 800px ).

How do I resize the handler, without limiting his movement ?

Is it also possible to change the input max value after criation ?

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/rangeinput/scrollbar.htm   (stand alone version)

Comment: Done, the rest did not solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want. Change div to testarea if yes. You can set drag limit.

http://www.pagecolumn.com/javascript/drag_resize.htm

Comment: I can't see how this is related with the situation I had described !?!